# No deformation while using array on curve

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am trying to create some kind of wall on an elongated half a sphere curve using the array and curve modifier, but when using the curve modifier, the wall get deformed along the curve.
For this instance, I would like to keep the wall straight, so it will rotate only on the connection between each object wall.
I have tried to use a parent/child instancing, the result is okay, but it seems that even that the wall (child) is 1m by 1m, and the face (parent) there are some overlapping vertices.

Any ideas?
Just to make it clear—I do not want a smooth curve, I would like to have jagged straight on a curve.

example .blend file attached

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get this effect with the help of geometry nodes:

[image]

it might be necessary to play around with Count of the resample node and maybe you should extrude the curve on the last point so that it fits perfectly.

I scaled the curve down on the y axis, just to prove that the wall isn't bended:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did not think of using geometry nodes, I do need to start practising.
@Chris Just one more question, Is there a way to merge the vertices of the connection points of each wall using geometry nodes? -

Comment: Using geometry nodes - no, AFAIK. But of course you can add a welding modifier after the geometry nodes modifier which does what you want!

Comment: :) True, Thanks for all the help